# Creating a Dynamic/Visual Systems Diagram from Energy Flows

Tags: user-interface, diagram

I am working on a technical engineering solution of connecting systems to other systems throughout a building environment. I am attempting to create a diagram that visually shows an input energy and then flow it through a series of systems, each of which will use a portion of that energy for operation. The diagram will update with different operations based on amount of energy, time of day, location, and desired output (heating or cooling).

The problem I have is that I need an extremely visual way of laying this out in a dynamic way. This all sounds super technical but to simplify, I'm basically creating a systems operation diagram (OR workflow diagram) that needs some serious power and visualization. I hope to make this a powerful tool in which, environmental data will automatically alter the diagram's configuration.

I am comfortable with learning a programming language if necessary but I'm just not sure which will be the best. I would like to start simple with one configuration and keep implementing new parameters. I was looking at Python, JavaScript, C++, C#, and VisualBasic. I almost imagine this like a game design for aesthetics but I'm not sure.

Below is a static example of the systems diagrams created for one specific case. This example is only the diagram and lacks any interactivity. Basically I would like to make a dynamic and interactive diagram that can take inputs and alter itself. But for starters, change visually with specific button presses.

[image: UI mockup]
<sup>[Original](http://www.flickr.com/photos/92091521@N04/9071075244/)</sup>

Comment: Do you expect huge business logic?

Comment: Not so much. Primarily input files that anyone could obtain from a weather website. It doesn't need to connect to servers or databases. Though, it would need to handle code and data manipulation as I intend to integrate addition systems.

Comment: The diagram/program will be highly interconnected. An alteration in input will change all downstream systems.

Comment: I thought even low-rep users can post URLs to images, just not embed them in posts. (That said, I'm not sure.)

Comment: Also, if you don't actually know a programming language yet, I'm not sure there's anything SO can help you with. You're describing a fairly complex tool and you're most likely to at best get vague suggestions for bits of this. (Like, say, Tk's Canvas or wxWidgets' OGL to take care of the display part.) Especially since you're not actually asking a question about a specific programming problem.

Comment: I know a bit of python, javascript, and C++ but I am in no way an expert in these.

Comment: @millimoose With a reputation of 10 I can post an image.

Comment: @JustinShultz What I meant is: can you post just the URL of the image? Without using the `![alt text][1]` markup? Someone can just edit it into an embed later.